# mockito: How to match varargs in java 8?

Tags: java, mockito, java-8

I'm working on migrating a project from java 7 to 8, and have gotten a compilation error in a Mockito "when" case I'm having a hard time tracking down:

```
when(queryRunner.query(any(String.class), any(ResultSetHandler.class), anyVararg())).thenReturn(mockedWordResultList);
```

gives me a compilation error of:

```
java: reference to query is ambiguous   both method
<T>query(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler<T>)
in org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner and method
<T>query(java.lang.String,org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler<T>,java.lang.Object...)
in org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner match
```

This error happens in build 1.8.0-b128, but doesn't happen in 1.7.0_45. I'm using mockito 1.9.5.

What's the correct way to use `anyVarArg()` argument matching in java 8?

Comment: I don't have Java 8 handy, so I can't test this easily; but what happens if you cast the third argument to `Object[]` ?

Comment: I tried using any(Object[].class) but it didn't match.

Comment: My question was what if you cast it.  In other words, pass `(Object[])anyVararg()` as the third argument.

Comment: Nice catch!!! That fixed it. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to do a bit more research into why this happened before I make an answer out of it.  Clearly, Java 8 has changed how it resolves type parameters, and it may be that Mockito will need a change to match.  Most likely, we'll end up adding a method like `public <T> T[] anyVarargOf(Class<T>)` or something of that kind to `Matchers`.  But at this point, I just don't know enough to be able to write a good answer.

Comment: would it help if I write a breaking test and put it up on github?

Comment: Thanks for offering.  I'll think about it.  Chances are I won't look at this till the weekend anyway.  I'll ping you here if I need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the type inference has been improved. `anyVararg()` is a generic method but you are using it in a nested method invocation. Before Java 8 the limitations of the type inference forced treating the method `<T> T anyVararg()` like `<Object> Object anyVararg()` when placed as an argument to another method invocation without inserting explicit type arguments.

So only `query(String, ResultSetHandler, Object...)` matched as the third argument was treated as being of type `Object`.

But now with Java 8 type inference works with nested method calls. Since for `<T> T anyVararg()` the type parameter `<T>` can be just *anything*, it can be `ResultSetHandler` as well. So `query(String,Object,ResultSetHandler)` also is a match candidate now.

<sup>(I omitted the type parameter `<T>` from the outer call in both cases to make it less confusing)</sup>

Since we have two possible matches now, the normal procedure of method selection applies here. And yes, it’s ambiguous. The first parameter is the same, `String`, but for the other two `ResultSetHandler` is more specific than `Object` but while one candidate accepts a more specific type for the second parameter, the other does for the third (and follow-ups).

It’s clear that type parameters that allow a method’s return type to be just anything are a source of ambiguity but APIs like Mockito’s containing such methods are a corner case of Java programming. You will have to force a type either the generic way `Matchers.<Desired>anyVararg()` or via type cast `(Desired)anyVararg()`.