# Mockito verify method fails with Object... args after upgrading Java

Tags: java, mockito

After upgrading to Java 8 a test, which previously worked, has started to fail.
Here is the test part:

```
    verify(session, times(1)).reject(any(), any(), any());
```

Here is the reject method:

```
public void reject(@SuppressWarnings("hiding") String fieldName, Object... args) {
    reject(fieldName, null, args);
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
ruleSession.reject(<any>, <any>, <any>);

However, there were other interactions with this mock:

ruleSession.reject(
    "year",
    2000,
    2000
);
```

As you can see, the reject method is actually called, but Mockito can't identify it. I'm guess it has something to do with Object... args

However when running the method with two args:

```
    verify(session).reject(any(), any());
```

The error is:

```
Actual invocation has different arguments:
ruleSession.reject(
    "year",
    2000,
    2000
);
```

I'm using Mockito version 1.10.19

Comment: why don't you use anyString(), anyInt()?

Comment: Java 8 parameter type inference improved, so Mockito is using a "more appropriate" overload of your `reject` method. See: [How to match varargs in java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22620664/1426891)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It appears that I need to replace

    verify(session, times(1)).reject(any(), any(), any());

with:

        verify(session, times(1)).reject(any(), anyVararg());

As the old way no long works in Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I need to replace

```
verify(session, times(1)).reject(any(), any(), any());
```

with:

```
verify(session, times(1)).reject(any(), anyVararg());
```

As the old way no longer works in Java 8.